# Elliptic curve theory : Injection from $\widehat{E(K)}$ to $E(K_v)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, local-field

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$.
Let $\widehat{E(K)}$ be profinite completion of $E(K)$.//

Let $v$ be a place of $K$.
Let $K_v$ be completion of $K$ at $v$.

Is there an injection from $\widehat{E(K)}$ to $E(K_v)$ ?
How can we construct it ?

---

**Background of this question:**

I encountered a beautiful exact sequence of Tate-Shafarevich group $Sha(E/K)$,
$$0\to Sha(E/K)\to H^1(G_K,E) \to \bigoplus_{v} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}\to {\widehat{E(K)}}^*\to0$$　where $*$ is Pontryagin dual.

However, I couldn't understand what the last map $\bigoplus_{v} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}\to {\widehat{E(K)}}^*$ is. If there is a map $\widehat{E(K)}\to \prod_v E(K_v)$, we can take its Pontryagin dual and that is the map we wanted. However, what is the map $\widehat{E(K)}\to \prod_v E(K_v)$ ? If I can embed $\widehat{E(K)}$ to $E(K_v)$, that's ok, so this question arised.
Another direct approach to this background is also appreciated.

Comment: To dot i's: $\widehat{E(K)}$ is the pro-finite completion of $E(K)$, and its dual $\widehat{E(K)}^* $ works out to be  $\text{Hom}_{cts} (E(K), \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ (continuous homomorphisms, with the co-finite topology on the domain, and discrete on the co-domain) - correct?

Comment: @peter a g  Than you, you are correct. I should have added that.

Comment: @peter a g  The problem may be very elementary, but the background is difficult, so I cannot attach attention of this question.

Comment: Have you looked at Milne's https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf, e.g., b) of page 83? I must confess that I have not read this book - and I certainly should have - so I was hoping that someone else would answer.

Comment: @peter a g. Isn't the answer to this question simple ? Since $\widehat{E(K_v)}=E(K_v)$, there is a natural map $\widehat{E}\to \prod_v \widehat{E(K_v)}$ ?